# What word describes someone who is the object of certification?

Tags: single-word-requests

Certifiers perform certifications, but whom do they certify? I'm not able to find the related form in a few different dictionaries:

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/certify)
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certify)
- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/certify)

The word I would choose is 'certee', but that is not recognized as a word in said dictionaries. For example, "The certee proudly displayed her certificate in a prominent location."

Comment: It's a bit of a "nonce word" (certainly not in the full OED), but here's this from Dominion Law Reports (1912) - [*The certificate there had issued, as stated above, subject to two encumbrances put on by the **certificatee** herself.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+certificatee+herself%22&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQwqTy7LbhAhXZSxUIHVMwCIoQvgUIKSgB&biw=1428&bih=747&dpr=1.2) IMHO, "certee" is a non-starter.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers; prompted by your suggestion, I've found several usages of 'certificatee' throughout the last century. If you would like to convert your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I closevoted (as Primarily Opinion-Based), so I don't think I'll do that. The bottom line is that so far as I'm concerned there is no single-word term for the meaning you seek. But English is nothing if not flexible, so I coined the nonce word myself, and double-checked the full OED to confirm that they don't list it (as expected). Then I searched for it in Google Books (and found some instances - again, as expected). There might be other terms with broadly overlapping meaning, but I can only see one credible "nonce derivative" based on the root word ***certify***.

Comment: Fair enough; thanks for your input nonetheless.

Comment: Certifier certifies a Claimant?

Comment: *accreditee*, from *accreditation*, might roll off the tongue a little more easily.

Comment: Are you asking about the point where the *applicant* is applying to be certified or after they have been certified: the *certificate holder*

Comment: I'm asking about the point after they have been certified.

Comment: There is some modest usage of "certificant" in this sense.  But the major dictionaries don't include the word.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

- the **certified party**

Once the person or entity has requested or applied for some certification, they may hold a certificate or may have been conferred some certification or attestation.

I think "certified party" is wide enough to cover any such meanings.

Answer (score 0):

A ***recipient*** is the one who receives the certification from the certifier.

> The ***recipient*** proudly displayed her certificate in a prominent
>   location.

ODO:

> **[recipient](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/recipient)**
>   *NOUN*
>   A person or thing that receives or is awarded something.
>
> ‘the recipient of the Nobel Peace Prize’

Answer (score 0):

a **holder**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/holder)

> a person, such as an owner, who has possession or control of something

As in:

the holder of a certificate